# Blu-Ray authoring on an Apple Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x, bluray

hope this is the right place for this query

I am after some advice on authoring blu-ray discs on a Apple Mac, I normally use Apple DVD Studio Pro from the FCP studio package, but this does not offer BR authoring.

Adobe Encore is not supported anymore and after reading some reviews didn't even really work that well.

I mainly do Wedding DVD's so there is a basic menu (4/5 buttons) with a short video background so this is all im looking for, I have Toast but it doesn't offer the customization I need, going direct from FCPX only gives me the option for the current timeline which is no good as I have multiple videos to add.

I have a BR burner in the Mac and it does work with Toast so im just after the App to build the BR image and I can burn it with Toast, like I currently do with DVDSP.

I could run a Windows VM if needed but it would be come messy when trying to move the files back and forth and trying to get the right codecs/supported files etc, but if this is my only option I am willing to look into it.

OR if anyone has any other options I would be open to suggestions.

EDIT: preferably free or a low price but im willing to look at all avenues, baring in mind this is not a huge money making operation this will be a few BR discs per year

Comment: Posting as a comment since this isn't an answer in and of itself, but stay away from Sonic's product line.  Scenarist might be ok, but when I tried their next to top line product (at the time DVD Producer) it was a buggy, unstable piece of garbage that I wasted $2500 on.

Comment: Cheers @AJHenderson, I been doing more research and it is looking like ill be stuck with trying Adobe Encore or removing BR from my list and maby subbing it for a digital download or something